# Working with Centroids

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-transformation

The question is as follows:

> Points $D$ and $E$ are marked on segments $AB$ and $BC$, respectively. When segments $CD$ and $AE$ are drawn, they intersect at point $T$ inside triangle $ABC$. It is found that segment $AT$ is twice as long as segment $TE$, and that segment $CT$ is twice as long as segment $TD$. Must $T$ be the centroid of triangle $ABC$?

I don't know where to start from. Please help! 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since $ATC\sim ETD$ with coefficient of similarity $k=2$ we have that $AC||DE$ and $DE=AC/2$ so $DE$ is middle line and thus conclusion.

If it is easier to you, look at homothety at $T$ which takes $A$ to $E$. Then it takes $C$ to $D$ and thus $AC||DE$ and $DE=AC/2$ again...

Comment: I see that $DE$ is the midline of $\triangle ABC$, but I don't know why that would relate to $T$ being the centroid of the triangle?

Comment: What is centroid?

Comment: The intersection of the medians.

Comment: And what is a middle line?

Comment: The line parallel to the base and and has half the length of the base.

Comment: So what are it end points?

Comment: The bisectors of the two edges of the triangle, but with the diagram that I drew $DE$ doesn't go through point $T$.

Comment: But $DE$ should not go through $T$, no?

Comment: $T$ is the intersection of $AE$ and $CD$. It lies on those lines only, but it doesn't seem to lie on $DE$.

Comment: Why should $T$ lie on $DE$?

Comment: Should it? I don't think it should, but if $T$ was a centroid, then it would.

Comment: Well I'm lost now, I really don't now what are we talking. Can you please repeat what is your problem now?

Comment: I need to verify whether $T$ is the centroid or not. I have included my diagram in the question.

Comment: So what are $D$ and $E$ since $ED$ is middle line? And what are $DC$ and $AE$

Comment: It is stated in the problem. $D$ is a point on $AB$ and $E$ is a point on $BC$. We needed to intersect $CD$ and $AE$ at point $T$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66784/discussion-between-geo-freak-and-john-watson).

Answer (score 0):

hint:

let $[ABC]$ denote are of triangle

$[ABT] = \frac{[ABC]}{3}$ similarly $[BTC] = \frac{[ABC]}{3}$

So, we get $[ATC] = \frac{[ABC]}{3}$